# VLC 2.0.1 Adjust Subtitle Tming

Tags: vlc

How can i adjust subtitle timing on VLC 2.0.1
My Subtitle late 2 minutes.

Already tried google, most of tutorial written for version 1, and version 2 has different configuration interface which it is more confusing for me.

Answer (score 19):

In windows, Go to   Tools --> Track Synchronization

or Click on the button  [image: Extended Settings Icon] from the VLC skin to open the extended settings

In Mac, Go to Window --> Track Synchronization

Comment: there is no menu tools sir. sorry i forgot to mention. I use VLC on MAC

Comment: @GusDeCooL, for Mac MenuBar -->  Window -->  Track Synchronization